# Are SqlDataSource wild cards pageable

Tags: c#, sql

I am using Visual Studio 2010, C#, with a `SqlDataSource`. I have a database of different types of recipes. I have encountered a problem when I use a `WHERE` clause with wildcards.

I can query the database and display the recipes in a pageable and sortable `GridView` or `ListView` if I use a standard query like

```
SELECT * From PostedRecipes
```

The problem happens when I use a wildcard query such as

```
SELECT RecipeName 
From PostedRecipes 
WHERE RecipeName LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%'  
GROUP BY RecipeName
```

If the database has 100 recipes with 30 sandwich recipes, for example, and I do a search on "sand" then the 30 sandwich recipes will be displayed. If the page size is set to 30, and there are 30 sandwich recipes, then 30 recipes will be displayed, but are not sortable.

The problem is not in getting the `WHERE` with wildcards to work, but rather having the results be pageable and sortable.

If the page size is changed to 10, then 10 sandwich recipes will be displayed with an indicator that there are 2 more pages available. If the 2nd or 3rd page is clicked, the page is blank.  If "sort" is clicked, the page returns blank.

Using Visual Studio, it is not necessary for me to add any code behind for the above results to be returned.

I cannot find any documentation or literature on this particular subject regarding whether it is possible to do what I am trying to do or not - that is, have a pageable and sortable `GridView` or `ListView` using a wildcard, per above. The properties of `SqlDataSource` are set to `DataSet` and cache is enabled. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

EDIT

This is the source page  - Search.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Search.aspx.cs"  Inherits="RecipeFaire.Search" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head id="Head1" runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="RecipeName"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" 
        PostBackUrl="~/GridTest3.aspx" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Search .cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;



 namespace RecipeFaire
 {
 public partial class Search : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }   

 }
 }
```

This is a sortable and pageable page but contains no WHERE clause.  It renders all recipes in the database  - GridTest2.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GridTest2.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridTest2" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT [RecipeID], [RecipeName], [Description] FROM  [PostedRecipes]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RecipeID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecipeID" HeaderText="RecipeID" InsertVisible="False"
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="RecipeID"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecipeName" HeaderText="RecipeName" SortExpression="RecipeName">
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" SortExpression="Description">
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
   </div>
   </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Code behind for GridTest2 which was generated by Visual Studio - GridView.cs

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class GridTest2 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

 }
 }
```

Code for page with WHERE clause.  This page renders the searched term recipes but will not page or sort - GridTest3.aspx

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GridTest3.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridTest" %>

 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">

<div>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:RecipeUploadConnectionString %>" 

        SelectCommand="SELECT [RecipeID], [RecipeName], [Description] FROM [PostedRecipes] WHERE ([RecipeName] LIKE '%' + @RecipeName + '%') 
        GROUP BY RecipeID, RecipeName, Description ORDER BY RecipeID, RecipeName, Description">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:FormParameter FormField="RecipeName" Name="RecipeName" Type="String"  />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="RecipeName" HeaderText="RecipeName" 
                SortExpression="RecipeName"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" 
                SortExpression="Description"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

    </div>
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Code behind for GridTest3.aspx generated by Visual Studio - GridTest3

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

 public partial class GridTest3 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

}
}
```

Comment: Your question is phrased unfortunately - there's no reason why a nontrivial query would be nonsortable, much less nonpageable. (You either fetch all the rows and do this on the client, which is very easy but inefficient. Or you automatically change the query to add the paging/sorting clauses - whatever the SQL Server equivalent to `LIMIT..OFFSET` is, and `ORDER BY`.) Give some example of the code you're using to wire up your `GridView` to a nontrivial query, and ask how to make it pageable+sortable on either the client or the server.

Comment: As far as "unnecessary to add any codebehind" goes, it's probably necessary to have your question be answered - it's not very simple to share the state of a GUI designer surface via prose, so you should do as little there as practical for the sake of your question.

Comment: millimoose, please see my edit with code above.

Comment: Why does your second query have a `GROUP BY` and an `ORDER BY`? I'm not sure that those should change anything, but the first seems unnecessary, and the second would interfere with any sorting done by ASP.NET

Comment: Also, lateral suggestion: use [ASP.NET 4.5's model binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822927.aspx#modelbinding) and LINQ-to-Entities or LINQ-to-SQL. It's touted as the preferrable option to using data source controls. (For one it's less inscrutable, and paging and sorting works for anything that returns `IQueryable`.)

Comment: The WHERE will not work without the GROUP BY or ORDER BY but works just as well if the ORDER BY is or isn't present, as least at the point I am now.  Thanks for the suggestions.